# MUI library display more than one value with visual emphasis using DateCalendar component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using the [DateCalendar](https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/date-calendar/) component from the MUI library, this component receives a value that has a visual emphasis on the calendar.I'm trying to make more than one date have an emphasis on the calendar, but I'm not succeeding.

The result I wanted is this:
[expected outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYZqH.png)

I tried to style each day individually through the slots but it styles them all

```
           <LocalizationProvider
              dateFormats={{ monthAndYear: "MMMMMMMMM" }}
              dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}
              adapterLocale={ptBR}
           >
                <DateCalendar
                  dayOfWeekFormatter={dayOfWeekFormatter}
                  disableHighlightToday
                  views={['day']}
                  className={styles.teste}
                  showDaysOutsideCurrentMonth={false}
                  value={new Date()}
                  fixedWeekNumber={0}
                  referenceDate={new Date(currentDate.getFullYear(), 1, 1)}
                  slotProps={{day: {
                               sx: {
                                 "&:nth-of-type(1)": {
                                      color: #fff;
                                      background-color: #1976d2;
                                      font-weight: 500
                                    },
                                 }
                               }}}
                />
            </LocalizationProvider>
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! There is a full example on the docs https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/date-calendar/#dynamic-data

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.